# Any solution as how a database version tool should be?

Tags: database, version

I am trying to making a tool which can help in maintaining data base version(like maintaining source code version). The technology which I am thinking to use is spring-hibernate so that the tool can be web based and it can be used by multiple project . The idea is that any database change can only be triggered with the help of this tool,so that the database version information can be maintained and the database can be made consistent .Operations like commit,roll back,branching,merging should be possible. Can you suggest me that how should I approach to this problem?

I have found an opensource tool called [LiquidBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) which has already provided some sort of solution in maintaining database version. Here is a short preview on [what this tool can do](http://www.liquibase.org/swf/overview_short/liquibase%20overview.html). But this tool has some limitations like it does not handle stored procedures and triggers and it works on the basis of an XML file . But I think I can integrate this tool with my requirement and I can speed up development. If you have any other tool in knowledge which can be better than this then please let me know.

If possible tell me that how the tool should be organized so that different project can easily maintain their database version. What all problem the tool should try to address and what minimum support should at least be there in this tool? What should be the UI so that user should be easily able to use it.?

Comment: If you are using maven for your project, check this one https://github.com/m-szalik/dbpatch-maven-plugin